# Cisco Routing through VPN

Tags: routing, cisco

I am looking for a way to allow a client Win7 computer, which connects to our California office's Cisco ASA 5510 over an IPSec VPN connection to then be able to connect to a computer in our chicago office which is itself connected through another Cisco ASA router to california.

It appears that we are unable to route client vpn connections between each other, and I cannot find any guidance on how to enable this. Let me know if this is possible / what needs to be done.

Comment: Just did some googling to see if i could help and i found this thread. http://serverfault.com/questions/111406/route-traffic-on-vpn-to-another-interface-on-an-asa-5510 thought it might help.

Answer (score 1):

I take it that the client computer is using the the Cisco VPN Client to connect to a Remote Access VPN on the California ASA. Then the California ASA connects to the Chicago ASA via a Site-to-Site VPN.

The California ASA must include the IP network that is being used in the Remote Access VPN as part of the Local Network. The Chicago ASA mustinclude the IP network that is being used in the Remote Access VPN as part of the Remote Network. If I remember correctly, these are set in your Crypto Maps.

If you are doing Split Tunneling on the Remote Access VPN, you also need to make sure that the Chicago networks are configured to be tunneled through the California ASA.